# Достать информацию из id в контакте

Tags: java, android

Кто может подсказать, каким образом можно сделать следующее. Есть список id-шников контакта. Необходимо извлечь по id фио и сохранить аватар в sql или просто в listview.

Comment: покажите код, как вы это попытались сделать

Comment: едва ли здесь есть смысл показывать какой-либо код, потому как конкретной проблемы нет - просто абстрактная задача..

Comment: пока ничего нет, т.к. не понятно как реализовать

Comment: Открыть страницу по ID, распарсить, сохранить. Очевидно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как не знаю JAVA, приведу пример на PHP, а Вы там под свой ЯП сами сделайте.

```
$user_ids = '1,2,5'; // список id пользователей ВКонтакте

$users_get = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$user_ids.'&fields=photo_400_orig'), true);

print_r($users_get);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 1
                    [first_name] => Pavel
                    [last_name] => Durov
                    [photo_400_orig] => http://cs629231.vk.me/v629231001/c536/dcqdvDEUs4E.jpg
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 2
                    [first_name] => Alexandra
                    [last_name] => Vladimirova
                    [photo_400_orig] => http://cs623422.vk.me/v623422002/2035d/SBNpeN_toq0.jpg
                    [hidden] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 5
                    [first_name] => Ilya
                    [last_name] => Perekopsky
                    [photo_400_orig] => http://cs623823.vk.me/v623823005/bb55/1mA3W35oDsA.jpg
                )

        )

)
```

Коротко говоря, нужно слать запрос сюда https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1,2,5&fields=photo_400_orig

**user_ids** - перечисленные через запятую идентификаторы пользователей или их короткие имена (screen_name).

Подробнее о методе **users.get** -> http://vk.com/dev/users.get

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос имеет слабое отношение к Android и Java, но, как понимаю, вам необходимо произвести реализацию именно для этой платформы.

Дело в том, что данная задача имеет довольно много решений. Самое очевидное из них - использовать API VK, который отдает контент в JSON формате. Далее этот контент благополучно "распарсить" его с помощью встроенного [JSON-парсеров](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) в Java.

Иной вариант:

- выкачать содержимое страницы([URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html))
- использовать [HTML парсеры Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) для выделения нужных данных
- сохранить данные в нужном виде в базу данных/куда-вам-нужно

Очевидно, что первый вариант позволяет сосредоточиться на проблеме, а не на её реализации. С точки зрения Android это и было бы наиболее приемлемо.

Comment: в группе в вк есть перечень id пользователей, необходимо их сохранить  в sql, т.к. вручную делать не вариант, разрабатываю под android поэтому такие метки указал.

Comment: Если есть статичный список id, то можно написать небольшой JS-скрипт для браузера, который бы выводил все id в консоль(браузера).
Затем этот статичный список можно сохранить в ресурсах приложения к примеру, после чего уже применять все тот же API VK.

Comment: В консоль он будет выводить просто id, а мне нужно как то вытащить инфу из id не переходят по ним это все тоже через js делать?